# fusion charts passing parameters split with comma creates some error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here I have function that will call fusion charts that will listed below charts are working fine. Here what was the problem is while I'm passing the parameter the splitting the comma due to this value

Here I'm passing the values from php

```
$categoryvalue = '{"label":"Q1"},{"label":"Q2"},{"label":"Q3"},{"label":"Q4"},{"label":"Q5"},{"label":"Q6"}';

$setvalue1=  `'{"value":"0"},{"value":"244"},{"value":"65"},{"value":"52"},{"value":"169"},{"value":"40"}';

$setvalue2 ='{"value":"0"},{"value":"37"},{"value":"53"},{"value":"5"},{"value":"45"},{"value":"4"}'
```

**Script**

```
<script>
function fusioncharts(type,rendernamew,w,h,xaxisname,yaxisname,labelname1,labelname2,categoryvalue,setvalue1,setvalue2){
 // here code starts
}
</script>
```

**Error**

> fusioncharts('mscolumn2d','chartContainer','900','400','Quarter','Revenues (In USD)','Incidents Submitted','Incidents Resolved',{"label":"Q1",{"label":"Q2",{"label":"Q3");

Now it says some error like this

> FusionCharts.js:158 Uncaught TypeError: a.match is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just you can add the `[` this in both string. This will solve you

```
$categoryvalue = '[{"label":"Q1"},{"label":"Q2"},{"label":"Q3"},{"label":"Q4"},{"label":"Q5"},{"label":"Q6"}]';

$setvalue1=  '[{"value":"0"},{"value":"244"},{"value":"65"},{"value":"52"},{"value":"169"},{"value":"40"}]';

$setvalue2 ='[{"value":"0"},{"value":"37"},{"value":"53"},{"value":"5"},{"value":"45"},{"value":"4"}]'
```